# Numpy outputting unicode from tostring()

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, flask

```
 if request.method == "POST":
    data = [[1,1]]
    data = sc.transform(data)
    rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 200)
    rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)
    my_prediction = rfc.predict(data)
    return my_prediction.tostring()
```

Somehow the code outputs � �V�.

This is also returned in Flask so I don't know if that is part of the problem.

Comment: May be you have to do this `return str(my_prediction)` ....would you print `my_prediction` and update Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up converting the array to a list and then to a string with join. Don't know what caused this but it worked.

```
  if request.method == "POST":
    genderquery = request.form['genderquery']
    agequery = request.form['agequery']
    data = [[genderquery,agequery]]
    data = sc.transform(data)
    rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 200)
    rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)
    my_prediction = rfc.predict(data)
    my_prediction = my_prediction.tolist()
    my_prediction = ''.join(my_prediction)
    print(my_prediction)
    return render_template('results.html',prediction = my_prediction, gender = genderquery.upper())
```